# Activating main window when button is clicked in a user control

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a WPF user control with some buttons inside it. I need to intimate the main window when button click happens inside the WPF control. The main window has to initiate some actions upon receiving this message from the button click event inside the user control.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a Click handler to all your Buttons, and in that Click handler, call the UserControl's OnClick method to generate a click event coming from the user control.

Answer (score 0):

Check out `Commands`:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752308.aspx